# Using an External Display with Vertical Dock Mac

Tags: multiple-monitors, suspend

Like the title says, is there a way to connect a Macbook Pro 2015 to an external monitor through a vertical dock?

The vertical dock requires that the laptop be closed, but when I close it to put it into the dock I am unable to resume through my keyboard/mouse. I know I can disable suspend on lid close, but I'd like to find a way without leaving the screen on.

Thanks!

Comment: Which Ubuntu release do you use?

Comment: I'm using 16.04 with 4.13.1 kernel. Also the dock is the Henge Vertical Dock, in case you needed that for reference